# Why is it wrong to ask "Est-ce que voulez-vous acheter combien de timbres ?"

Tags: interrogative

This is from https://www.fun-mooc.fr/ A2 level chapter 4.8. The question is to select two  alternate ways of asking "*Combien de timbres vous voulez acheter ?*"

The options are

1. > Combien voulez-vous acheter de timbres ?
2. > Combien est-ce que vous voulez acheter de timbres ?
3. > Est-ce que vous voulez acheter combien de timbres ?
4. > Est-ce que voulez-vous acheter combien de timbres ?

Only the first two are listed as correct. Why are the latter two incorrect?

Comment: Do want you buy how much stamps?

Answer (score 3):

When an interrogative word like *combien* is used alongside *est-ce que*, they always combine together and the interrogative word doesn't stay where it would be in a declarative sentence:

- Tu viens [à pied].
- Tu viens [comment] ?
- [Comment] tu viens [∅] ?
- [Comment] viens-tu [∅] ?
- [Comment] est-ce que tu viens [∅] ?

But never:

- *Est-ce que tu viens [comment] ? (the asterisk at the beginning of the sentence indicates it's not grammatical)

or:

- *Tu viens [comment] est-ce que ?

You can think of it like *est-ce que* dragging the question word to the beginning of the sentence. The third and fourth answers violated this rule, which is the reason why they weren't correct.

Furthermore, est-ce que can never be used with inversion, making the fourth answer doubly wrong:

- *[Comment] est-ce que viens-tu [∅] ?

---

**Extended comment over word order in interrogatives and the *est-ce que* particule**

There's a handful of question words that don't exist in the formal language and can't be put at the beginning of a question. In those cases, they can't be used with *est-ce que* at all:

- Elle est [grande comment] ? (How tall is she?)
- *[Grande comment] elle est ?
- *[Grande comment] est-ce qu'elle est ?
- *[Grande comment] est-elle ?

With *combien de X*, things are a bit more complicated because the question word can be either *combien* alone, in which case the *de X* part stays in situ, or the whole *combien de X* phrase:

- Vous voulez acheter {[cinq] timbres}.
- Vous voulez acheter {[combien] de timbres} ?
- [Combien] vous voulez acheter {[∅] de timbres} ?
- [Combien] voulez-vous acheter {[∅] de timbres} ?
- [Combien] **est-ce que** vous voulez acheter {[∅] de timbres} ?
- {Combien de timbres} vous voulez acheter {∅} ?
- {Combien de timbres} voulez-vous acheter {∅} ?
- {Combien de timbres} **est-ce que** vous voulez acheter {∅} ?

As you can notice, *est-ce que* always goes after the whole interrogative word or phrase. It can't split it, so the sentence below is incorrect:

- *{Combien} **est-ce que** {de timbres} vous voulez acheter {∅} ?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to form a question in French: putting the subject after the verb (“*Es-tu là ? Où vas-tu ? D'où viens-tu ?*”), “*est-ce que*” (“*Est-ce que tu es là ?* Où est-ce que tu vas ? D'où est-ce que tu viens”), and the informal way of using the affirmative syntax with a rising tone at the end of the sentence (“Tu es là ? Tu vas où ? Tu viens d'où ?”).

With the first two ways, if there is a question word like *où*, *quand*, *combien*, *comment*, *pourquoi*, *quel(le)(s)*, etc. then this question word must come at the beginning of the sentence. The only thing you can have before the question word is a preposition. Thus:

> Combien voulez-vous acheter de timbres ? — Je veux acheter trois timbres.
>   Combien est-ce que vous voulez acheter de timbres ? — Je veux acheter trois timbres.
>   De combien de timbres avez-vous besoin ? — J'ai besoin de trois timbres.
>   De combien de timbres est-ce que vous avez besoin ? — J'ai besoin de trois timbres.

If the question doesn't start with a question word, it's a yes/no question. You can't turn it into an open-ended question mid-way.

> Voulez-vous acheter des timbres ? — Oui.
>   Est-ce que vous voulez acheter des timbres ? — Oui.

There is one exception: in informal spoken French, you can form a question by using the normal affirmative syntax, and indicate that it's a question by using a rising tone. In this case, we normally put the question word at the same place that the answer would go.

> Vous voulez acheter combien de timbres ? — Je veux acheter trois timbres.
>   Vous avez besoin de combien de timbres ? — J'ai besoin de trois timbres.

Even in this case, it's also possible to put the question word at the beginning.

> Combien de timbres vous voulez acheter ? — Je veux acheter trois timbres.
>   De combien de timbres vous avez besoin ? — J'ai besoin de trois timbres.